# How to transform files with embedded Jetty before serving them?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

This is the code I am using to serve static files from the filesystem with embedded Jetty.

```
    String directory = "dir";
    final ContextHandler contextHandler = new ContextHandler();
    final ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
    contextHandler.setContextPath("/" + directory);
    resourceHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(new File(directory,
                directory);
    contextHandler.setHandler(resourceHandler);
```

How do I modify this to transform the files before serving them?

I would like to continue using ResourceHandler and ContextHandler to avoid reimplementing the useful logic in those classes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It is to wrap the Resource that your code passes to ResourceHandler.setBaseResource() with a class like this:

```
public class TransformingResource extends Resource {
    private Resource resource;

    protected TransformingResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isContainedIn(Resource r) throws MalformedURLException {
        return resource.isContainedIn(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        resource.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists() {
        return resource.exists();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDirectory() {
        return resource.isDirectory();
    }

    @Override
    public long lastModified() {
        return resource.lastModified();
    }

    @Override
    public long length() {
        transform();

        return transformed.length();
    }

    @Override
    public URL getURL() {
        return resource.getURL();
    }

    @Override
    public File getFile() throws IOException {
        return resource.getFile();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return resource.getName();
    }

    private String transformed;

    private void transform() {
        if(transformed != null) {
            return;
        }

        transformed = transformInputStream(resource.getInputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        transform();

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(transformed.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    }

    @Override
    public ReadableByteChannel getReadableByteChannel() throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete() throws SecurityException {
        return resource.delete();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean renameTo(Resource dest) throws SecurityException {
        return resource.renameTo(dest);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] list() {
        return resource.list();
    }

    @Override
    public Resource addPath(String path) throws IOException,
            MalformedURLException {
        Resource toReturn = resource.addPath(path);
        if(toReturn == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return new TransformingResource(toReturn);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to break HTTP Response Caching and HTTP request security, you'll need to provide overrides for `.getReadableByteChannel()`, `.getAlias()`, `.lastModified()`, and `.getWeakETag()` as well.  (Be sure you provide a Weak ETag that is transform aware, like its done in the Gzip filters)

Comment: Don't delegate to the underlying `Resource` for those overrides (they are now invalid per your `TransformingResource` implementation) - there's a reason Jetty didn't use this technique for the `AsyncMiddleManServlet` and `MiddleManServlet` based transformers it ships with.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you for the feedback. If the transform is deterministic then I don't think that the class needs to override `.getAlias()` or `.lastModified()` since that data is the same as the underlying resource. I think that the class doesn't need to override `.getWeakETag()` because `Resource.getWeakETag()` calls the member methods of `TransformingResource` which are correct. I also think that the class does not need a different implementation of `.getReadableByteChannel()` because many `Resources` simply return null (e.g the `URLResource` class hierarchy.) Please let me know if you a

Comment: URLResource is probably going to disappear in the future, as its very hostile to Servlet 3.x and jar included `META-INF/resource/` entries.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you for that information. Do you know what method will be used to serve files embedded in JARs when the jetty application is packaged with a tool like maven shade?

Comment: as yet undetermined, probably something similar to JarResource, but several options are being discussed.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you. I'm sure it will be a good replacement.

Answer (score 3):

ResourceHandler does not support modifying the contents in-stream (on the fly).

The ResourceHandler is optimized to send the files in as efficient a manner as possible, typically using Memory Mapped file buffers, serving the file directly from disk to the network with next no buffer handling of the file in Java memory.

You have 2 choices:

1. Modify the files on disk, in a separate step or process (not on the fly)
2. Write your own file serving handler that can modify the files on the fly.

You can use the [FastFileServer example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.10.v20150310/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/FastFileServer.java) from the Jetty git repository as a good starting point for choice #2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I found a way that allows reuse of of the ResourceHandler and any type of Resource. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: One reason that I wish to use the Resource infrastructure classes is to be able to use any of the different kinds of resources, especially JarResource.

Comment: Know that Resource isn't really meant to be an overridable class structure, its kind of an internal interface, and is subject to change.  We even had a conversation *today* about overhauling URLResource and JarResource due to all of the old Java 1.3 hacks present in them.  Even Jetty 9.3 is replacing FileResource with a new PathResource.

Comment: Thank you. One of the great things about Resource is that an application can interact with its resources the same way regardless of if the app is deployed in a jar or running from the file system during development.